# using a json feature as variable in img scr

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm a total newbie to javascript and web maps. I'm trying to create a map that displays murals around the city. When you click on the point, I want image of the map to pop-up.  Here's what I have so far:

```
var address = feature.properties.address || 'Unnamed address';
var artist = feature.properties.artist || '(Unknown)';
var year = feature.properties.Year|| '(Unknown)';
var photo = feature.properties.image|| '<P>Photo not available</P>';
var titleHtml = '<p style="font-size:18px"><b>' + address + artist +'</b></p>';


document.getElementById('summaryLabel').innerHTML = titleHtml;
document.getElementById('muralImage').innerHTML = '<img scr='+ photo + '/>'

L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e); // stop click event from being propagated further
          }
        });
      }
      map.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (selection) {
          if (selectedLayer === muralsLayer)    selection.setIcon(iconByPassday(selectedFeature));

          selection = null;

          document.getElementById('summaryLabel').innerHTML = '<p>Click a mural on the map to get more information.</p>';
          document.getElementById('muralImage').innerHTML = ''
        }
      });

    }
```

It's obvious to me that the following is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
document.getElementById('muralImage').innerHTML = '<img scr='+ photo + '/>'
```

Comment: The attribute of an `img` pointing to its source URL is `src`, not `scr`.

Comment: *Forhead slap.  Thank you